# WinJs background application

Tags: winjs, windows-10-universal

I am working on creating a Windows 10 Universal app. My goal is to have the app run in the background and periodically display a status notification to the user.

I've seen a few articles that talk about creating a background task within the app (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-), is this the best design pattern I can follow? I'm fairly new to Windows Universal apps and any recommendations on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [IBackgroundTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks) docs. In addition, you can easily implement notifications via the OS with [Adaptive Toasts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts)

Since the story around notifications can get complex depending on how you want to control UX, don't be afraid to research building an RT component if you can't find a UWP API that meets your needs. For instance, you can package an RT component with your UWP app that calls into native C++ libraries or more low-level Windows APIs to curate the notification experience for your user.